# How to create a Socket Server in Python

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to receive audio data via WIFI from an android device. The code shown is a working example from the forum which I used for my problem, but is written in Java. Is there a similar solution in python, which can replace the java server? What is the equivalent code for this java code in python.

```
class Server {

AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
static AudioInputStream ais;
static AudioFormat format;
static boolean status = true;
static int port = 50005;
static int sampleRate = 44100;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[3548];
    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

    while (status == true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData());

        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());

        // A thread solve the problem of chunky audio
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
            }
        }).start();
    }

    // serverSocket.delete();
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(6.0f);

        sourceDataLine.start();
        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        sourceDataLine.start();

        System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a code translation service. Show us some effort!

Comment: google search -> socket server python | google search-> stackoverflow socket server python.

Answer (score 0):

A server in Python can be created using the module socket.

If you want to make / create your own socket server, you can define your own application protocol. You can also use it to work with existing apps.

You have to do the following things (globally):
- Bind the socket to a port and start listening.
- Wait for client to receive data.

I found the code below on the web: The only thing you have to do, is change the settings to your own situation.

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''  
PORT = 7000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('# Socket created')

# Create socket on port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('# Bind failed. ')
    sys.exit()

print('# Socket bind complete')

# Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print('# Socket now listening')

# Wait for client
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('# Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

# Receive data from client
while True:     
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    line = data.decode('UTF-8')    # convert to string (Python 3 only)
    line = line.replace("\n","")   # remove newline character
    print( line )     

s.close()
```

once the code runs, it can always receive data.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal:

```
import socket                
s = socket.socket()          
port = 12345                

s.bind(('', port))         
s.listen(5) # "socket is listening"            

while True: 
   c, addr = s.accept()      
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send('Thank you for connecting') 
   c.close()
```